# Show uploaded picture instead of upload button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a "button" (an anchor that acts like a button). Where you can upload a picture that gets previewed.

But what I want to do is to make the uploaded picture to be displayed instead of the button (same size etc). Is there a nice way of doing this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                $('#imageChosen').attr('src', event.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $('#fileInput').change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
});
```

```css
div.input {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#filebutton {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>for testing</title>

 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/costum.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/costum.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="input">
  <label for="fileInput">
   <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" />
   <a style="display: block;" type="button" id="filebutton">Upload</a>
   <img id="imageChosen">
  </label> 
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                $('#imageChosen').attr('src', event.target.result);
                $("#imageChosen").show();
                $("#fileInput").hide();
                $("#filebutton").hide();
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $('#fileInput').change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
});
```

```css
div.input {
 display: inline-block;
}

#filebutton {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

#imageChosen{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>for testing</title>

 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/costum.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/costum.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="input">
  <label for="fileInput">
   <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" />
   <a style="display: block;" type="button" id="filebutton">Upload</a>
   <img id="imageChosen" style="display:none;">
  </label> 
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get some white space at the bottom of the picure with this.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the image as a background via `$('div.input').css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')')`?

You might then want to set the `background-size` to either `cover` or `contain`.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(event) {
        $('div.input').css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $('#fileInput').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
});
```

```css
div.input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#filebutton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">
  <label for="fileInput">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" />
    <a style="display: block;" type="button" id="filebutton">Upload</a>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach, based off of your solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgChosen = $('#imageChosen');
  var inputElm = $('.input');

  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        $('#imageChosen').attr('src', event.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $('#fileInput').change(function() {
    readURL(this);
    inputElm.hide();
    imgChosen.fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
#fileUploadWrapper {
  display: relative;
}

div.input {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#filebutton {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#imageChosen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileUploadWrapper">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="fileInput">
      <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" />
      <a id="filebutton">Upload</a>
    </label>
  </div>
  <img id="imageChosen">
</div>
```

Comment: I get an error when running your snippet. Have you included jquery in it?

Comment: Looks nice. But now you cant upload another picture if you want to change it.

Comment: Your original question states "But what I want to do is to make the uploaded picture to be displayed INSTEAD of the button"

Answer (score 0):

Created a snippet.

Changed background-size to 100% 100% in case it's the desired behaviour.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var buttonWidth,
      buttonHeight;

    function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
      
            if (typeof buttonWidth === 'undefined') {
               buttonWidth = $('#filebutton').outerWidth();
            }
            if (typeof buttonHeight === 'undefined') {
               buttonHeight = $('#filebutton').outerHeight();
            }
            
            reader.onload = function (event) {
              var img = $('<div class="imageChosen"></div>');
                img.css({
                 'width': buttonWidth,
                  'height': buttonHeight,
                  'background': 'url(' + event.target.result + ') center top no-repeat',
                  //'background-size': 'cover'
                  'background-size': '100% 100%'
                });
                if ($('#filebutton').length) {
                 $('#filebutton').replaceWith(img);
                } else {
                 $('.imageChosen').eq(0).replaceWith(img);
                }
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $('#fileInput').change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    
});
```

```css
div.input {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#filebutton {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>for testing</title>

 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/costum.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/costum.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="input">
    <label for="fileInput">
      <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" />
      <a style="display: block;" type="button" id="filebutton">Upload</a>
    </label> 
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks nice, but it does not display the entire image. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: If you need the image to be the same width and height as the button then since an image can have different ratio it would get distorted without background-size: cover. If you need only the width to be the same, then sure the height can be auto and instead of background-image you can go with an <img> tag.

Comment: Changed background-size to 100% 100% in case it's the desired behaviour.